# Created by display in email when creating a new task

Tags: workflow, email, user

So I created a workflow which sends an alert email to specific user. The content of email is to say which user created a task. In string builder of email content I use [%Current Item:Created By%] but in email this is showed like **i:0#.w|sprax\** itsollutions.user2.

How do i remove the bolded part?

Comment: Do you have Claims Authentication?

Comment: You can se by the login name that they are using claims @Sergey

Comment: Are you using designer workflow?Do you want to show display name or login name of the user in email?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Sharepoint Designer Workflow on 2010 platform. I want to show display name, currently it shows login's name with bolded part. Display name would be best, but solution of login name without bolded part would be great too.